# Sort Android Application based on usage

Tags: android

I want to list the Installed application based on there usage. By Usage I mean the duration, an application has been used in one full day.
So far I am able to list all installed application in the phone.

How can I sort the list based on there Usage?

Please let me know at-least the method / class which can be used to do so.

I have used PackageManager to list all installed Packages.

Comment: do you want to list the background service application too??

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartappers.appusage&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5zbWFydGFwcGVycy5hcHB1c2FnZSJd and https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.agrvaibhav.AppUsageTracking&hl=en

Comment: No, for now. Basically I want to get the Activity running time. Say if I start collecting background service time then any native web application will be used for full day(Facebook, G-mail). I just want to record the time you were in running state for say Facebook app. Likewise for other application.

Comment: Please don't post application. I need the method/ class / logic to achieve the target.

Comment: sorry i think you will not get any thing like that from here,if you try some thing you will surly get help

Comment: And the second app, I think it is listing the cpu time for the application(App Usage Tracker).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57133/discussion-between-user3065701-and-sreekanth).